# System Error : Xamp installation dll file missing error

Tags: apache, windows-7, xampp

I have been using `Xamp` for long time. but now days after installation when I try to start `apache`   my `windows7` 32-bit PC which showing one error

> api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll file is missing

and the alert box showing a recommendation to reinstall the `Xamp` to fix this problem.but I tried it several times and still which showing the same error(**Note**:- it's MySql is working fine).Please help me.I'm added the screen shot below.Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: try running Xampp as administrator...

Answer (score 0):

try installing Visual C++ Redistributable (x86)  packages from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/developer-tools.aspx)
this should work