# Alternative for XAMP on windows7

Tags: windows-7, xampp, localhost

I'm currently doing a project which needs storage of data(dynamic website).But project is local project(local host).I have been using XAMP now days but which is not supporting now.[Xamp installation problem -  no fix is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568535/system-error-xamp-installation-dll-file-missing-error)Which is the best local server side program that can I use for this project.I'm tied of searching on google because I don't get any useful information,please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you could use **WAMP** as a local server. It is the best alternative for **XAMP** and you will get lots of support available on internet as well.
It is easy to use so go for **WAMP** as an alternative for your local server.
Here is the link from where you can download it-
http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: tnx for your help